# Including / embedding Python interpreter with C++ exe and Pybind

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cross-platform, wxwidgets, pybind11

I need to distribute an application that must be cross-compiled and runs on Windows and Linux platforms. The application is a C++ `wxWidgets` based UI.  In addition, I need functionality from Python3 that I want to access via `PyBind`.

I can include whatever I want in the distribution (usually a zip archive), but I cannot install anything on the target machine.  For example, the appropriate MSVC run-time libraries are distributed with the Windows version.  But there is no installer or modification to the registry.  The executable is run out of the same directory as these shared libraries.

When it comes to Python, I can't be sure that it is installed on the target machine (or that a minimum version is installed).  I will also need to make user of certain Python libraries that might not be available, even if a Python interpreter is available (e.g., `numpy, scipy, matplotlib`).  So these also need to be included in the application distribution.

Given all of the above, can I compile against a known version of Python (and therefore `#include` that version's `Python.h` file) link against the appropriate static libraries?  Or should include the runtime as a dynamically linked library along with my executable?  And how do I include the specific Python libraries (e.g., `numpy`) in this set-up?

Or what would be the best way forward given the above description?

And what pitfalls / problems might I encounter if other versions of Python are installed on the machine already?

Comment: I use the embedded version of Python for Windows and the software has pip installer to manage pip packages (numpy, scipy, wxPython etc..).  wxWidgets is compiled with shared=1 flag. Take a look at https://www.sciencesuit.org

Comment: @MadeleineP.Vincent, wouldn't it be easier to make you software with wxPython and then create a distribution with i.e. Anaconda?

Comment: @Igor - there is too much in C++ to change to wxPython

Comment: @macroland - this looks promising. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @MadeleineP.Vincent - no worries! Btw, you can ship numpy, scipy with the embedded Python but the size of the installer will increase significantly. That's why I let user to install via GUI.